# React & Fetch async/await... Why I'm receiving a promise?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I'm having some troubles about react, fetch and async/await.

I have this code as a fetch wrapper:

```
export const fetcher = (url, options = null) => {

  const handle401Response = error => {
    throw error;
  }

  const isResponseValid = response => {
    if (!response.ok)
      throw response;
    else
      return response.json();
  }

  return fetch(url, { ...options, credentials: 'include' })
    .then(isResponseValid)
    .catch(handle401Response);
}
```

Then I define some API calls functions like:

```
export const getGroups = (id = null) => {
  return fetcher(`${API_GROUP_URL}${id !== null ? `?id=${id}` : ''}`);
}
```

And then I try to use it like:

```
export function SomeComponent(props) {

  const groups = async () => {
    try {
      const ret = await getGroups();
      return ret;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  console.log(groups());
  
  return <h1>Component</h1>
}
```

The result in console is: Promise{}.
I have read docs about async/await but can't understand why await is not waiting for promise to end.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export function SomeComponent(props) {

  const [data, setData] = useState()

  const groups = async () => {
   
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const ret = await getGroups();
      // process and set data accordingly
      setData(ret)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    }

    // fetch data inside useEffect
    fetchData()

  }, [])

 // console.log(groups());
  
  return <h1>Component {data?.prop}</h1>
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea on how to fetch in a functional component

Answer (score 1):

Async functions always return a promise. The time when you call that function it will give you back a promise instantly. You have used await inside the function and it is waiting for getGroup promise.

In normal javascript function `console.log(await)` this will fix the issue but in react you have to do it inside a another function because you cant make react components async (at least not in React 17 and below)

Comment: Manoj, thanks for your reply. So, for example, I should use useEffect() hook and define and call the async function inside it?

Comment: Well, you should for now if you are just starting with React. Later you can also try third-party libraries suggested by the React team like react-query which helps with data fetching, caching and many more. You should read this article https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects